# ı writing data process pipeline with luigi but ı get error

Tags: python, data-science, pipeline, data-extraction, luigi

```
import os
import luigi
import pandas as pd
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class DownloadData(luigi.Task):

    def run(self):
        site = req.get("http://www.gutenberg.org/browse/scores/top").text
        with self.output().open("w") as f:
            f.write(site)

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("raw_data.txt")

    def complete(self):
        return os.path.exists(self.output().path)

class PrePData(luigi.Task):

    def requires(self):
        return DownloadData()

    def run(self):
        data = self.requires()
        bs4ed_data = []
        if data.contains("<!DOCTYPE html>"):
            bs4ed_data.append()(data,"html.parser")

        else:
            print("can not found any problem in this data")

        return bs4ed_data

    def output(self):
        return luigi.local_target("data.txt")

    def complete(self):
        return os.path.exists(self.output().path)

    def on_success(self):
        print("data preprocessing completed successfully")

    def on_failure(self):
        print("data preprocessing failed")

class RunAllTasks(luigi.WrapperTask):
    def requires(self):
        return [DownloadData(),PrePData()]
```

ı run this python file with this command in my terminal

```
python -m luigi --module PipeLineofETL-A RunAllTasks --local-scheduler --workers 4
```

and error

```
python -m luigi --module PipeLineofETL-A RunAllTasks --local-scheduler --workers 4
DEBUG: Checking if RunAllTasks() is complete
WARNING: Will not run RunAllTasks() or any dependencies due to error in complete() method:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 429, in check_complete
    is_complete = check_complete_cached(task, completion_cache)
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 414, in check_complete_cached
    is_complete = task.complete()
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/task.py", line 845, in complete
    return all(r.complete() for r in flatten(self.requires()))
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/task.py", line 845, in <genexpr>
    return all(r.complete() for r in flatten(self.requires()))
  File "/home/tuna/Belgeler/GitLab/extractdata/ChatGPT's Basic tasks/PipeLineofETL-A.py", line 40, in complete
    return os.path.exists(self.output().path)
  File "/home/tuna/Belgeler/GitLab/extractdata/ChatGPT's Basic tasks/PipeLineofETL-A.py", line 37, in output
    return luigi.local_target("data.txt")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

INFO: Informed scheduler that task   RunAllTasks__99914b932b   has status   UNKNOWN
INFO: Done scheduling tasks
INFO: Running Worker with 4 processes
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Done
DEBUG: There are no more tasks to run at this time
INFO: Worker Worker(salt=1404147006, workers=4, host=tunapc, username=tuna, pid=9077) was stopped. Shutting down Keep-Alive thread
INFO: 
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 1 tasks of which:
* 1 failed scheduling:
    - 1 RunAllTasks()

Did not run any tasks
This progress looks :( because there were tasks whose scheduling failed

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====
```

```
import os
import luigi
import pandas as pd
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class DownloadData(luigi.Task):

    def run(self):
        site = req.get("http://www.gutenberg.org/browse/scores/top").text
        with self.output().open("w") as f:
            f.write(site)

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("raw_data.txt")

    def complete(self):
        return os.path.exists(self.output().path)

class PrePData(luigi.Task):

    def requires(self):
        return DownloadData()

    def run(self):
        data = self.requires()
        bs4ed_data = []
        if data.contains("<!DOCTYPE html>"):
            bs4ed_data.append()(data,"html.parser")

        else:
            print("can not found any problem in this data")

        return bs4ed_data


class RunAllTasks(luigi.WrapperTask):
    def requires(self):
        return [DownloadData(),PrePData()]
```

ı write same command in terminal and ı get this error

```
DEBUG: Checking if RunAllTasks() is complete
/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/task.py:845: UserWarning: Task PrePData() without outputs has no custom complete() method
  return all(r.complete() for r in flatten(self.requires()))
DEBUG: Checking if DownloadData() is complete
DEBUG: Checking if PrePData() is complete
/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/worker.py:414: UserWarning: Task PrePData() without outputs has no custom complete() method
  is_complete = task.complete()
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   RunAllTasks__99914b932b   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   PrePData__99914b932b   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   DownloadData__99914b932b   has status   DONE
INFO: Done scheduling tasks
INFO: Running Worker with 4 processes
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Pending tasks: 2
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Done
DEBUG: There are no more tasks to run at this time
DEBUG: PrePData__99914b932b is currently run by worker Worker(salt=3997262702, workers=4, host=tunapc, username=tuna, pid=10617)
INFO: [pid 10624] Worker Worker(salt=3997262702, workers=4, host=tunapc, username=tuna, pid=10617) running   PrePData()
ERROR: [pid 10624] Worker Worker(salt=3997262702, workers=4, host=tunapc, username=tuna, pid=10617) failed    PrePData()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 198, in run
    new_deps = self._run_get_new_deps()
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 138, in _run_get_new_deps
    task_gen = self.task.run()
  File "/home/tuna/Belgeler/GitLab/extractdata/ChatGPT's Basic tasks/PipeLineofETL-A.py", line 28, in run
    if data.contains("<!DOCTYPE html>"):
AttributeError: 'DownloadData' object has no attribute 'contains'
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   PrePData__99914b932b   has status   FAILED
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Done
DEBUG: There are no more tasks to run at this time
DEBUG: There are 2 pending tasks possibly being run by other workers
DEBUG: There are 2 pending tasks unique to this worker
DEBUG: There are 2 pending tasks last scheduled by this worker
INFO: Worker Worker(salt=3997262702, workers=4, host=tunapc, username=tuna, pid=10617) was stopped. Shutting down Keep-Alive thread
INFO: 
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 3 tasks of which:
* 1 complete ones were encountered:
    - 1 DownloadData()
* 1 failed:
    - 1 PrePData()
* 1 were left pending, among these:
    * 1 had failed dependencies:
        - 1 RunAllTasks()

This progress looks :( because there were failed tasks

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====
```

when ı added output() method to DownloadData in requires function, ı get this error

```
DEBUG: Checking if RunAllTasks() is complete
/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/task.py:845: UserWarning: Task PrePData() without outputs has no custom complete() method
  return all(r.complete() for r in flatten(self.requires()))
DEBUG: Checking if DownloadData() is complete
DEBUG: Checking if PrePData() is complete
/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/worker.py:414: UserWarning: Task PrePData() without outputs has no custom complete() method
  is_complete = task.complete()
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   RunAllTasks__99914b932b   has status   PENDING
ERROR: Luigi unexpected framework error while scheduling RunAllTasks()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 794, in add
    for next in self._add(item, is_complete):
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 892, in _add
    self._validate_dependency(d)
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 917, in _validate_dependency
    raise Exception('requires() can not return Target objects. Wrap it in an ExternalTask class')
Exception: requires() can not return Target objects. Wrap it in an ExternalTask class
INFO: Worker Worker(salt=6506578324, workers=4, host=tunapc, username=tuna, pid=10710) was stopped. Shutting down Keep-Alive thread
ERROR: Uncaught exception in luigi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/retcodes.py", line 75, in run_with_retcodes
    worker = luigi.interface._run(argv).worker
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/interface.py", line 213, in _run
    return _schedule_and_run([cp.get_task_obj()], worker_scheduler_factory)
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/interface.py", line 171, in _schedule_and_run
    success &= worker.add(t, env_params.parallel_scheduling, env_params.parallel_scheduling_processes)
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 794, in add
    for next in self._add(item, is_complete):
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 892, in _add
    self._validate_dependency(d)
  File "/home/tuna/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 917, in _validate_dependency
    raise Exception('requires() can not return Target objects. Wrap it in an ExternalTask class')
Exception: requires() can not return Target objects. Wrap it in an ExternalTask class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error in the first block because `luigi.local_target` is a module while `luigi.LocalTarget` is the class you were looking for.

The second error is because you most likely don't want to be using `self.requires` directly in `PrePData.run`, but instead want to use `self.input()` (take a look at https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#task-run). `self.input()` will return the outputs of the required task, which in this case is `DownloadData`.

Finally, there are a couple optimizations you can make to your code:

1. In luigi, if a `LocalTarget` is specified as an output, it's mere existence signifies that the task is complete. This is actually the default implementation of `Task.complete`, so you don't need to reimplement it yourself.
2. You don't need to specify all the tasks in `RunAllTasks`. Luigi will automatically discover required tasks and construct the requirements tree before resolving the entire tree. Therefore, you only need to specify the top-level tasks, which in this case is just the `PrePData` task.